# How to render checked checkboxes using CSS alone?

Tags: css, checkbox

This is may be very noobish and a bit embarrassing but I am struggling to figure out how to make checkboxes 'checked' using CSS?

The case is that if a parent has a class `setup` (for example) I'd like to have all the checkboxes having `setup` as parent to be checked. I'm guessing this is not doable in pure CSS, correct? I don't mind using JS but am just very curious if I could toggle the state of the checkboxes along with that of their parent (by toggling the class).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nupul/5SZMg/) to play around with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A checkbox being "checked" is not a style.  It's a state.  CSS cannot control states.  You can fake something by using background images of check marks and lists and what not, but that's not really what you're talking about.

The only way to change the state of a checkbox is serverside in the HTML or with Javascript.

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle of that pseduo code.  The things is, it's rather pointless.

It means you need to adding a CSS class to an element on the server that you want to jQuery to "check".  If you're doing that, you might as well add the actually element attribute while you're at it.

http://jsfiddle.net/HnEgT/

So, it makes me wonder if I'm just miss-understanding what you're talking about.  I'm starting to think that there's a client side script changing states and you're looking to monitor for that?

**EDIT 2**

Upon some reflection of the comments and some quick digging, if you want a JavaScript solution to checking a checkbox if there's some other JavaScript plugin that might change the an attribute value (something that doesn't have an event trigger), the only solution would be to do a simple "timeout" loop that continuously checks a group of elements for a given class and updates them.

All you'd have to do then is set how often you want this timeout to fire.  In a sense, it's a form of "long polling" but without actually going out to the server for data updates.  It's all client side.  Which, I suppose, is what "timeout" is called. =P

Here's a tutorial I found on the subject:

http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/

I'll see if I can whip up a jQuery sample.

**UPDATE**

Here's a jsfiddle of a timeout listener to check for CSS classes being added to a checkbox and setting their state to "checked".

http://jsfiddle.net/HnEgT/5/

I added a second function to randomly add a "checked" class to a checkbox ever couple of seconds.

I hope that helps!

Comment: @PhD I've added a second update to which I think I better understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in *pure* css.

However, you could have a jQuery event which is attached to all elements of a class, thereby triggering the check or uncheck based on class assignments.

Perhaps like this:

```
function toggleCheck(className){
 $("."+className).each( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("checkedOn");
 });
 $(".checkedOn").each( function() {
  $(this).checked = "checked";
 });
}
```

Comment: An example please? Pseudo code would be fine too. How do I listen for class assignment??

Comment: Pseudo code?  `if forall(form checkboxes) has CSS class '.checked' { element.checked(true); }`.  I believe that's what Travis J is saying.

Comment: @jmbertucci - I got that much :) I'm wondering how to listen for class  toggle? Custom events?

Comment: Ah, are you familiar with jQuery?  I'll update my answer quick.  It wouldn't be hard.

Comment: @PhD - Actually, while beginning to write a "simple" example I realized that although you can attach an event to any class on a page, it is not that easy to listen for a class toggle. I am not sure if you would like my hack for doing that as it may slow down the page.

Comment: @PhD - I am now curious as to jmbertucci's solution :) Perhaps I will put a not exactly best practice example in, with the caveat of - use as is.

Comment: @PhD - You could add a callback to your toggleclass call.

Comment: @TravisJ - Yup...just figured that out :P

Comment: Are you saying if there's a JS that changes the class by adding `.checked` or something?  If there's a JS function that's adding such a class, why couldn't it change it's state too?  Or if there's some plugin that's out of your control changing the class state that you want to listen on?